# Is it possible to make the moving window in resample start from the most recent date?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset in a Pandas dataframe:

```
   id       date  value
    1  2019-01-31     10
    1  2019-02-28     15
    1  2019-03-31      8
    2  2019-01-31     20
    2  2019-03-31     10
```

Say I want to compute the cumulative sum of the *previous* two months for each id, while accounting for gaps in the data (e.g. missing months). In the example, the starting point for each id should be the most recent date: 2019-03-31.

The desired result is

```
   id       date  value
    1  2019-03-31     23
    2  2019-03-31     10
```

The code I wrote to try to do this is

`df.set_index('date').groupby('id')['value'].resample('2M').sum()`

which gives

```
                value
id date
1   2019-01-31    10
    2019-03-31    23
2   2019-01-31    20
    2019-03-31    10
```

When I try to get the cumulative sum for *three* months, the result I get is as follows:

`df.set_index('date').groupby('id')['value'].resample('3M').sum()`

```
                value
id date
1   2019-01-31    10
    2019-04-30    23
2   2019-01-31    20
    2019-04-30    10
```

where the expected result should have been

```
                value
id date
1   2019-03-31    33
2   2019-03-31    30
```

Any thoughts on how this can be achieved?

Pandas version: '0.25.1'

Comment: Try `closed='left'` in your `resample`

Comment: This works when the rule is `3M`. However, when I use a rule of `2M` it still sums the earlier dates first. The result is, for id = 1, a sum equalling to 25 and a sum equalling to the single value 8.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by `user3483203` use `closed='left'`. Putting it here so that you can close the question (please ask user3483203 to enter his suggestion as answer so that you can accept it)

```
df.set_index('date').groupby('id')['value'].resample('3M',closed='left').sum().reset_index(name='value')
```

**output**

```
id  date        value
1   2019-04-30  33
2   2019-04-30  30
```

Comment: Thank you. Will this work for 1M and 2M as well? I’m looking for a general solution that will work for an arbitrary number of months.

Comment: If you want only sums of values, the best way would be to resample by month & using a rolling window to get the sum for a number of time periods, something like below  first create a resampled df`a=df.set_index('date').groupby('id')['value'].resample('M').sum().reset_index(name='value')`, then do the operatinos on it `a.groupby('id')['value'].rolling(3).sum()` here you can change the value inside `rolling()` to get the sum.